# How to prove this inequality?$\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots+\frac{1}{n+n} + \frac{1}{4n} > \ln 2$

Tags: inequality, summation, harmonic-numbers

$$\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots +\frac{1}{n+n} + \frac{1}{4n} > \ln 2$$

$n$ is positive integer.

Thank you !

Comment: Hint: Approximate $\int_{n}^{2n} dt/t$ using the trapezoidal formula.  Since $1/t$ is a convex function, you should see that the approximation overestimates.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624984/how-prove-this-h-2n-h-n-frac14n-ln2

Comment: And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots +\frac{1}{n+n} + \frac{1}{4n}$$

Then

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{4n+4}-\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{4n}\\
 =\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{2}{4n+4}+\frac{1}{4n+4}-\frac{4}{4n+4}-\frac{1}{4n}\\
 =\frac{2}{4n+2}-\frac{1}{4n+4}-\frac{1}{4n} <0 $$

Thus, $a_n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence. As $\lim_n a_n = \ln 2$, it follows that

$$a_n > \ln(2)$$

**P.S.**

$$\frac{2}{4n+2} < \frac{1}{4n+4}+\frac{1}{4n}$$

can be easily proven by bringing everything to the same denominator, but it also follows from the HM-AM inequality:

$$ \frac{2}{\frac{1}{4n+4}+\frac{1}{4n}} < \frac{4n+4n+4}{2}=4n+2$$

Comment: \lim_n a_n = \ln 2 ？Would  please show me more detail? What is the evaluation of the limit?

Comment: @user104677 $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots +\frac{1}{n+n}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$ is a Riemann sum corresponding to $\int_{1}^2 \frac{1}{x} dx$. The extra term converges to $0$.

Answer (score 6):

Because $\frac 1t$ is concave up, its integral is overestimated by the trapezoidal approximation.  In this light, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\ln 2 = \int_n^{2n}\frac 1t dt &<
\frac 12 \left( \frac 1{n} + \frac 1{n+1} \right) +
\frac 12 \left( \frac 1{n+1} + \frac 1{n+2} \right) + \cdots+ 
\frac 12 \left( \frac 1{2n-1} + \frac 1{2n} \right)\\
&= \frac 1{2n} + \frac 12 \left( \frac 1{n+1} + \frac 1{n+1} \right) + 
\frac 12 \left( \frac 1{n+2} + \frac 1{n+2} \right) + \cdots \\
&\qquad+
\frac 12 \left( \frac 1{2n-1} + \frac 1{2n-1} \right) + \frac 12 \frac 1{2n}
\\
&= \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + ... +\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{4n} &=
\end{align}
$$
I hope that's clear.

Comment: @AWertheim, if $n$ is not positive then how do you interpret $$\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + ... +\frac{1}{n+n}$$ ?

Comment: @AWertheim I have taken the notation $\frac{1}{n+\mathbf{1}} + \frac{1}{n+\mathbf{2}} + ... +\frac{1}{n+\mathbf n}$ to imply that $n$ is there is an increasing sequence of integers $1,2,\dots,n$.  This would imply that $n$ is positive.

Comment: Ah, forgive me. Silly question! Thank you gentlemen.

Comment: I still wonder why $\frac1{4n}>\frac1n$...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, how does your first inequality follow?  It seems to be saying that $1/4n > 1/n$.  Also, your sum of integrals should be $\int_0^n \frac{dt}{n+t} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_k^{k+1} \frac{dt}{n+t}$  But then this is less than $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}$, not $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n+k}$.

Comment: I indeed said that for some reason.  I'm not quite sure what I was thinking. Let me see if this is salvageable.

Comment: There is still a typo in your sum of integrals.  The indices are off.

Comment: Fixed that.  It seems, however, that the integral is too low a lower bound. I think this is where Stephen's comment comes into play.

Comment: The indices are still off.  It is not true that $\int_1^n \frac{dt}{n+k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_k^{k+1} \frac{dt}{n+k}$.

Comment: All right.  Now, everything should be in order.

Comment: you're welcome :)